# How to append items from array to list

Tags: javascript, html, list, appendchild

I have an array "stringsArray" and I need to append all its items to a div as "li" items. That should happen when the person hovers over the div. The "li" elements should also be removed when the div is not being hovered anymore.
The problem is that when I hover the div, an infinite number of "li" elements is created. Also, the li elements are not being removed when not hovering. What is wrong with my code?

**HTML**

```
<div id="topics-div">Topics</div>
```

**JS**

```
let stringsArray = [
    "Topic 1",
    "Topic 2",
    "Topic 3",
    "Topic 4",
    "Topic 5"
]

let topicsDiv = document.getElementById("topics-div");

let topicUl = document.createElement("ul");

topicsDiv.onmouseover = function(){
    topicsDiv.append(topicUl);
       for(i = 0; i <= stringsArray.length; i++){
           let liElement = document.createElement("li");
           liElement.textContent = stringsArray[i];
           topiclUl.appendChild(liElement);
    }
}


topicsDiv.onmouseout = function(){
   let liElement = topicsDiv.querySelector("li");
       topicsDiv.removeChild(liElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of issues that need to be addressed. Here's the corrected version:

```js
let stringsArray = [
    "Topic 1",
    "Topic 2",
    "Topic 3",
    "Topic 4",
    "Topic 5"
];

let topicsDiv = document.getElementById("topics-div");
let topicUl = document.createElement("ul");

topicsDiv.onmouseover = function() {
    topicsDiv.appendChild(topicUl);

    for (let i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++) {
        let liElement = document.createElement("li");
        liElement.textContent = stringsArray[i];
        topicUl.appendChild(liElement);
    }
};

topicsDiv.onmouseout = function() {
    while (topicUl.firstChild) {
        topicUl.removeChild(topicUl.firstChild);
    }

    topicsDiv.removeChild(topicUl);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="topics-div">Topics</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Changes made:**

- Fixed the typo in `topiclUl` to `topicUl` in the loop where you are
  appending `li` elements.
- Changed the loop condition to  `i < stringsArray.length` to prevent accessing an undefined element in the array.
- Used a `while` loop to remove all child elements of the `ul` when the mouse leaves the `div`.

This should resolve the issue of infinite li elements being created and not being removed when not hovering.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- `liElement` will get only one `li` element, not all of them, so you cannot expect the `mouseout` handler to remove all of them.
- `topicsDiv` is not the parent of `liElement`, so `topicsDiv.removeChild(liElement)` will not work -- it will actually trigger an error which you should see in the console.
- In the `mouseover` handler you have a typo: `topiclUl` is not `topicUl`. Also this should lead to an error message in the console.

To fix this you could iterate over all `li` elements to delete them one by one, but it is much easier to just clear the content in the `ul` element, so just do:

```
topicUl.innerHTML = ""; // This removes all those LI elements
topicsDiv.removeChild(topicUl);  // Optional
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here the problem is in your onmouseout function. You need to remove all the li but your function is selecting li as query selector and then removing the child of the same.

what you need to do is you have to recursively remove the Li and ideally you should remove the UL as well as.

Here's is the working '**onmouseout**'-

topicsDiv.onmouseout = function () {
        // Remove all li elements
        while (topicUl.firstChild) {
            topicUl.removeChild(topicUl.firstChild);
        }

        // Remove the ul element- This is optional ideally you should remove the UL as well.
        topicsDiv.removeChild(topicUl);
    }
```